# Hest equation in radial coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative, heat-equation

Here is the heat equation in radial coordinates:

$\lambda \frac{1}{r} \frac{d}{dr}(r \frac{dT}{dr})+S(T)=0$

with S(T) being const and the boundary contions:

T(r1) =T1

T(r2) =T2

[image]

Can someone help me to find the analytic solution ?

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a bit more explanation on your setup? In addition to Boundary Conditions, the Helmholtz Equation does not specify a unique solution without a set of Initial conditions. It seems you assume the solution is radially symmetric, but it is unclear why your equation lacks a time derivative, or where the constant term $S(T)$ comes from. Are you looking for the steady state solution? This would be a solution to the Laplace Equation on these boundaries.

Comment: @Kajelad S(T) is a constant. and yes, you guessed correctly... I am looking for the steady state solution. :)

Comment: This is just the steady heat diffusion with the source $S$ which is constant throughout the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T'(r)=y(r)$, then
$$\frac{d}{dr}(ry(r))+\frac{S}{\lambda}r=0$$
or
$$y'(r)+\frac{1}{r}y(r)+\frac{S}{\lambda}=0$$
The integrating factor is
$$I=e^{\int\frac{1}{r}dr}=r$$
So,
$$y(r)=\frac{c_{1}}{r}-\frac{1}{r}\int{r}\frac{S}{\lambda}dr=\frac{c_{1}}{r}-\frac{Sr}{2\lambda}$$
and
$$T(r)=\int{y(r)}dr+c_{2}=c_{2}+c_{1}\ln(r)-\frac{Sr^{2}}{4\lambda}$$
Now the bc's
$$T_{1}=c_{2}+c_{1}\ln(r_{1})-\frac{Sr_{1}^{2}}{4\lambda}$$
$$T_{2}=c_{2}+c_{1}\ln(r_{2})-\frac{Sr_{2}^{2}}{4\lambda}$$
$$c_{1}=\frac{1}{\log(r_{1}/r_{2})}\Big(\frac{S(r_{1}^{2}-r_{2}^{2})}{4\lambda}+(T_{1}-T_{2})\Big)$$
$$c_{2}=T_{2}-\frac{\ln(r_{2})}{\log(r_{1}/r_{2})}\Big(\frac{S(r_{1}^{2}-r_{2}^{2})}{4\lambda}+(T_{1}-T_{2})\Big)-\frac{Sr_{2}^{2}}{4\lambda}$$

Comment: thanks a lot. Would you mind to explain me the steps of how you got y(r) with the integrating Factor ?

Comment: Equation of the form $y'+a(x)y=b(x)$ has solution $y=ce^{-\int{a(x)}dx}+e^{-\int{a(x)}dx}\int{e^{\int{a(x)}dx}b(x)}dx$. The first function in the solution $y=ce^{-\int{a(x)}dx}$ comes from the homogeneous part $y'+a(x)y=0$. The second is obtained using the integrating factor $I=e^{\int{a(x)}dx}$. Multiply the equation by $I$ to get: $e^{\int{a(x)}dx}y'+e^{\int{a(x)}dx}a(x)y=e^{\int{a(x)}dx}b(x)$ The lhs is $e^{\int{a(x)}dx}y'+e^{\int{a(x)}dx}a(x)y=\frac{d}{dx}(e^{\int{a(x)}dx}y)$, so $\frac{d}{dx}(e^{\int{a(x)}dx}y)=a(x)e^{\int{a(x)}dx}$ or $y(x)=e^{-\int{a(x)}dx}\int{e^{\int{a(x)}dx}b(x)dx}$

Comment: @Kirly Pesotski Thanks a lot ! but then how do you arrive at y(r)=c1/r - 1/r... ?

Comment: When i wrote the integrating factor is i meant $\int(1/r)dr$ is, the integrating factor is e^{\int(1/r)dr}=r

Comment: I'll edit it now

Comment: I think the log should be a ln, or the other way round in for c1 and c2...

Comment: I'm not an engineer, in physics we only use natural logs so it is a convention. I guess so do the math people do.